# SlickGrid button click handler stops functioning on scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

In attempting to use `SlickGrid` in my page, I have noticed that a `jQuery` click handler I declare after the grid is rendered only works for approximately 2x the number of rows visible.

Moreover, when a button is clicked the `value` property is changed to provide visual confirmation to the user. However, upon scrolling too far down past one of the previously clicked buttons, scrolling back up appears to reset the `value` to the original/default value.

As far as I can tell, it looks like the grid is re-rendering at various intervals. If that suspicion is correct, how do I preserve the effect of the click handler and the values in those buttons already clicked?

It may be important to note that I am not using dataView.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  var grid,
      data = [],
      columns = [
          { id: "rownum", name: "Row #", field: "rownum", width: 50 },
          { id: "accname", name: "Account Name", field: "accname", width: 500 },
          { id: "accid", name: "Id", field: "accid", width: 150 },
          { id: "rectypeid", name: "Record Type ID", field: "rectypeid", width: 150 },
          { id: "itemurl", name: "Item URL Link", field: "itemurl", width: 300, formatter: function (r,c,v,def,datactx) { return "<a target='_blank' href='" + v + "'>" + v + "</a>" } },
          { id: "rfrbtn", name: "Notify Staff", field: "rfrbtn", width: 75, formatter: function (r,c,v,def,datactx) { return "<input class='rfrch' value='Yes' type='button' id='" + datactx.accid + "'/>" } }
      ],
      options = {
        enableCellNavigation: false,
        enableColumnReorder: true,
      };

  var acc = new SObjectModel.Acc();

  // Query Accounts
  var count = 1;
  acc.retrieve({ where: {Name: {like: '%Test Acct%'}, RecordTypeId: {eq: '01230000003MJmr'}}, limit: 100 }, function(err, records, event){
    if(err) {
      alert(err.message);
    }
    else {
      records.forEach(function(record) {
        data.push({
          rownum: count++,
          accname: record.get("Name"),
          accid: record.get("Id"),
          rectypeid: record.get("RecordTypeId"),
          itemurl: record.get("itemurl")
        });
      });
    }
    grid.invalidate();
    rfrClickHandler();
  });

  grid = new Slick.Grid("#container", data, columns, options);

  var rfrClickHandler = function() {
    j$(".rfrch").click(function() {
      var rfrbtnClicked = j$(this).prop('id');
      j$(this).prop('value','Cancel');
      console.log(rfrbtnClicked);
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your code or may be put it in a fiddler?

Comment: Did you try my solution? I had to deal with the same issue and it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use .on() so that you do not have to re-bind the click handlers after the rows are re-rendered.

```
j$("#container").on('click', '.rfrch', function(){
    //... your handler code
}
```

In your formatter for the button you can add a property to dataContext for the current value state of the button and also a data property to hold the row index:

```
if(datactx.rfrchState === undefined){
    datactx.rfrchState = "Yes";
}
return "<input class='rfrch' value='"+datactx.rfrchState+"' data-row-index='"+r+"' type='button' id='" + datactx.accid + "'/>"
```

Then in your button handler add code to retrieve the data object and set rfrchState. That way when you scroll up and down and the rows are re-rendered the state will be preserved and set on the button via the formatter.

```
var rowIndex = j$(this).data('row-index');
var dataItem = grid.getDataItem(rowIndex);
dataItem.rfrchState = dataItem.rfrchState === 'Yes'?'No':'Yes';
```

Hope this helps.